# Almost sure convergence to a constant implies tightness of associated distributions

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of random variables where $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n=a$ almost surely, $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that the sequence of associated distributions is tight.

My attempt: I know that convergence a.s. implies convergence in probability, which in turn implies convergence in distributions. This means, by definition, that the distributions converge weakly, which implies that this sequence of distributions is tight. I have proofs for all these statements, but I am looking for a more direct way to prove this.

Comment: What is 'tight' in this context?

Comment: A sequence of distributions is tight if the sequence of their respective measures are tight - see "Tightness of measures".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  avoid going to convergence in distribution. Convergence in  probability is good enough.

$P(|X_n|>|a|+1) \leq P(|X_n-a|>1) <\epsilon$ if $n > $ some $n_0$. For $n \leq n_0$ choose $M_i$ such that $P(|X_n|>M_i) <\epsilon$ and take $M =\max \{M_1,M_2,...,M_{n_0}), |a|+1\}$.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I missed this. +1